# Functions and limits two directions

Tags: limits, functions

A really cunning question which I can't seem to solve.
If $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)=0$ does it necessarily means that $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\right)=0$ for ANY f'(x) which behaves like that?
Note: This isn't if-and-only-if. I need to either confirm or deny this question. I couldn't find a function that behaves like that, and this question seems to be always true but how can I prove it?

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sin'x = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \cos x$ does not exist.

Comment: I know that is exactly what I wrote, what about the other way around?

Comment: the numirator tends to Zero as x tends to infinity thus the fraction as a whole will tend to 0

Comment: No offense, but can you read what I wrote please? If the derivative approaches 0 as x approaches infinity, does it neccesarily mean that f(x)/x will approach 0 as x approaches infinity?

Comment: I was only referring to the example $f(x) = \sin x$ you gave. It cannot be used in demonstrating any part of the result in the first sentence because the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d}{dx} \sin x = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \cos x$ is not zero.

Comment: Yes, I was asked if this is always true. f(x)=sinx DENIES it which makes it false and that is a good answer for it. The opposite direction - I need to prove it, either true or false but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using L'Hospital rule for $k/\infty$ format:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0\impliedby\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=0$$
See if you can use the same for second part similiary.

Comment: But thats not always true. as I said, if $f\left(x\right)=sin\left(x\right)$ then $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{sinx}{x}\right)=0$ but $f'\left(x\right)=cosx$ and $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(cosx\right)$ is undefined. So you cannot use L'Hospital rule here.

Comment: I'll repharse the question.

Comment: L Hospital's rule is valid even when denominator tends to $\infty$ and the behavior of the numerator does not matter in this case. What is important to note is that the ratio obtained after differentiation of the numerator and denominator must tend to some limit or diverge to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh your comment seems contradictory to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) please help me.

Comment: @Aditya: Perhaps you have not read the whole wiki article. Check the proof of case 2 which deals with the case when $|g(x)| \to \infty$. It clearly mentions that we don't need the additional hypothesis regarding limit of $|f(x)|$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that's a good and new finding for me, thanks!

Comment: Aditya thanks for the effort and I'm with you, thanks for the finding @ParamanandSingh

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim _{x\to \infty }f'\left(x\right)=0$ then exists $K$ so that for every $x > K$ :   $|f'(x)| < \varepsilon$. Thus, by Lagrange's theorem on any interval $[K, N] (K < x < N)$: $$\left|\frac{f\left(N\right)-f\left(K\right)}{N-K}\right|<\varepsilon$$ 
As $K-N$ approaches $\infty$ follows $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}=0$ **Q.E.D.**

$\mathtt{\text{answered by Billy McGeen}}$